# registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener() approaches comparison

Tags: java, android, listener

In some code that I am maintaining I noticed two different ways to register a shared preference change listener:

(1) The straightforward approach, in which the class containing the registered member function implements [SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener.html#onSharedPreferenceChanged%28android.content.SharedPreferences,%20java.lang.String%29).

```
preferences.registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(mImageView);
```

(2) The indirect approach, in which the the class that *could have* contained the registered member function, prefers not to implement [SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener.html#onSharedPreferenceChanged%28android.content.SharedPreferences,%20java.lang.String%29) for some reason, and instead opts for defining and instantiating a whole new class dedicated only for this listener:

```
SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener mPreferencesListener = 
  new SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener() {
    public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences prefs, String key) {
      // do here what's needed to do
    }
  };


....

preferences.registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(mPreferencesListener);
```

Both work well but now I am wondering: Is one approach preferable over the other?

Are there circumstances in which *only one* of these 2 approaches could actually be used?

Answer (score 2):

This is up to implementation, in terms of maintainability some people may found one or other way better for their intentions, some people just go further thinking of readability, natural medicine, etc.

In the other hand of course you may want to prevent any leak and garbage collection issues, said if member created `mPreferencesListener` is accessing any of the enclosing instance methods you may run in some issues, as a good citizen you should unregister your listeners after you know that you will not be using them (e.g. onPause, onDestroy, etc.) and opt for static inner classes instead of member inner classes and be cautious when anonymous and local inner clases access enclosing instance methods/properties.

Finally is worth to mention that as for now [SharedPreferencesImpl](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blame/master/core/java/android/app/SharedPreferencesImpl.java) uses a [WeakHashMap](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/WeakHashMap.html) for its listeners.

Comment: Why do you say "it is up to implementation" if you clearly point to a win-win advantage of the straightforward approach #1? Not only #2 takes more lines of code, it is also more cumbersome to maintain (garbage collection issues, onPause, etc.), having to deal with the headache of `static inner` vs. `member inner` classes plus `anonymous` vs. `local` inner classes... Tell me please that you were kidding. :)  +1 already & I will accept your answer once I'm convinced that I fully understand it.

Comment: Unless we are involving here the [single responsibility principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle) but then this listener class should be neither anonymous nor inner...